# Apache Flink - SQL Kafka connector Watermark on event time doesn't pull records

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a question similar to the one [Apache Flink Tumbling Window delayed result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58907070/apache-flink-tumbling-window-delayed-result/65028326#65028326). The difference is, I'm using the SQL using kafka connect to read records from topic. I get the records on regular intervals, but somehow, I don't get the last few records in the output. For example, the last record in Kafka topic is with timestamp 2020-11-26T13:11:36.605Z and the last timestamp for aggregated value is 2020-11-26T12:59:59.999. I don't understand why I'm not getting the aggregation on the last record in topic. Please help. Here is my code.

```
sourceSQL = "CREATE TABLE flink_read_kafka (clientId INT, orderId INT, contactTimeStamp, WATERMARK FOR contactTimeStamp AS contactTimeStamp - INTERVAL '5' SECOND with (kafka config) ";
sinkSQL = "CREATE TABLE flink_aggr_kafka (contactTimeStamp STRING, clientId INT, orderCount BIGINT) with (kafka config) ";
aggrSQL = "insert into flink_aggr_kafka SELECT TUMBLE_ROWTIME(contactTimeStamp, INTERVAL '5' MINUTE) as contactTimeStamp, clientId, COUNT(*) orderCount from flink_read_kafka GROUP BY clientId , TUMBLE(commsTimestamp, INTERVAL '5' MINUTE)";
blinkStreamTableEnv.executeSql(sourceSQL);
blinkStreamTableEnv.executeSql(sinkSQL);
blinkStreamTableEnv.executeSql(aggrSQL);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, some background: A tumbling window only emits results once the watermark has passed the maximum timestamp of the window. The watermark indicates to the framework that all records with a lower timestamp have arrived, and hence the window is complete and the results can be emitted.

The watermark can only advance based on the timestamp of records coming in, so if no more records are coming in the watermark will not advance and currently open windows will not be closed. So, it is expected that last windows remain open when there is no influx of data anymore.

In your example, one would normally assume that the windows with a rowtime of 2020-11-26T13:04:59.999 and 26T13:09:59.999 are also emitted, because the latest records should have pushed the watermark beyond these timestamps.

I can think of two reasons right now why this might not be the case:

- not all **parallel** source instances have seen a timestamp higher than 26T13:05:04.999 and hence the output watermark has actually not passed that value. You can test this by either running the job with a parallelism of 1 which would mitigate the problem or verify if this is the case by checking the watermark of the window operator in the Flink Web UI.
- if you are using the Kafka producer in exactly-once mode and only consume records that have been comitted the records will only become visible once a checkpoint has been completed after the window has fired.

Comment: Thanks for the input, now the last record in topic is with timestamp 2020-11-29T13:43:21.454Z, watermark is not advancing. Here is data based on observation.

        Watermark mills Watremark in date   The aggregate time in file 
        1606655913666 2020-11-29 13:18:33.666 PM 2020-11-29 13:10:00.000
        1606656068881 2020-11-29 13:21:08.881 PM 2020-11-29 13:15:00.000
        1606656130974 2020-11-29 13:22:10.974 PM 2020-11-29 13:15:00.000
        1606656861744 2020-11-29 13:34:21.744 PM 2020-11-29 13:20:00.000
        1606657396454 2020-11-29 13:43:16.454 PM 2020-11-29 13:30:00.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your comment. When the last record in topic has timestamp "2020-11-29T13:43:21.454Z", what is the watermark time that you see in the web ui for the window operator? Is that higher than the end time of the any window that has not been emitted yet?

Comment: Sorry for formatting mess, this is the current state. The watermark is not moving forward, though there is record in Kafka. It can only move forward if I sent another record with current timestamp...So my observation is, aggregation is happening if there are records worh 5 minutes in Kafak, ie, from 2020-11-29T21:30:46.737Z to 2020-11-29T21:34:46.737Z. Somehow, aggregation is not taking remaining/latest Kafka records in consideration.
Current Watermark - 2020-11-29 21:30:41.737 PM, Last Record in Kafka - 2020-11-29T21:30:46.737Z and Last aggregate in File - 2020-11-29 13:40:00.000

Comment: There is a 8 hour lag between the latest aggregate and the latest events/watermark?

What is you window length and how many records do you see per second/minute?